# Prioritization of multiple TCP sockets within single process

Tags: c, windows, http, networking, tcp

I have multiple simultaneous tcp sockets downloading over http some large files. All of them (more than 10) are connected to the same host. All together these sockets max out all available network channel. I have another socket, which is connected to another host and I would like to prioritize this socket over all other sockets that max out networking channel. How can this be achieved? My goal is to change priority within my process, so that it wouldn't affect other processes.

Comment: [QOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374086.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable AFAIK, that's dead api.

Comment: The API is not dead. It's just not supported by operating systems after XP/Server 2003. The general consensus seems to be, that QoS should not be handled at the application/socket level.

Comment: Well... in my case I have a few sockets that max out connection, and I need to make sure that one of the sockets has 100% priority over the other sockets in *my* process. I know about qos and that for it to work it has to be supported by entire network path, which isn't usually a case. What I'm looking for is to ask OS (network drivers) to prioritize some my packets over the others. There is now [QoS2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374117(v=vs.85).aspx) in windows.

Comment: Why not simply have your app throttle the socket I/O calls that are using up all of the bandwidth?  You know which connection needs higher priority.  When a read/send call on a given socket finishes, if another socket has higher priority then just insert a small delay before calling the next socket read/send call for that lower-priority socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll try all kinds of approaches, but at the same time I have very specific requirement: I should try to minimize changes to the code that runs these 10 sockets that take over entire network connection. I'll first try QoS2 and see how it behaves.